# What is purpose of xmlconnect_notification_send_all cron job?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cron, core

In magento xmlconnect_notification_send_all is a core cron job.

What is exact purpose and scope of xmlconnect_notification_send_all cron job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Mage_XmlConnect` module is used for managing and configuring the mobile application connected to your website (if you have one).
I'm not 100% sure but I think that cron is used to send push notifications to the app users.

*Off topic*: If you don't have a mobile app you can disable that module by adding a new file in `app/etc/modules`. Call it `Zzzz.xml` (so it's loaded last) with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_XmlConnect>
            <active>false</active>
        </Mage_XmlConnect>
    </modules>
</config>
```